# jquery passing data to function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been struggling for a while with a problem, which I believe is very simple, yet I'm unable to solve. Can you tell me how to pass data to my function in the current example.

The situation is as follows

I'm generating new form elements with a button. But I would like to add the functionality of counting the word count for the new textareas, currently I'm able to just make it work for the first inputs.

HTML

```
<textarea class="cTxtW-<?php echo $k;?>" type="text" placeholder="50 word description"></textarea>
   <p id="count-<?php echo $k;?>"></p>
   <script>
      $( ".cTxtW-<?php echo $k;?>" ).keyup(function count('.cTxtW-<?php echo $k;?>', 'count-<?php echo $k;?>'));
   </script>
```

At the top of the page is my javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function count(txt, cnt){ 
    var txtVal = $(txt).val();
    var words = txtVal.trim().replace(/\s+/gi, ' ').split(' ').length;
    var chars = txtVal.length;
    if(chars===0){words=0;}
    $(cnt).html(words+' words');
}

</scirpt>
```

I'm adding new fields with the following code

```
var addDivS = $('#addServ');
    var k = parseInt($("#lS").attr('rel'))+1;
    $('#addNewServ').on('click', function() {
        if(k<=5){
            var inputsS = '<textarea name="servTxt[]" style="margin:10px 0 0 0;width:560px;height:60px;" class="inpt cTxtW-'+k+'" type="text" placeholder="50 word description"></textarea><p id="count-'+k+'"></p>'
            $(inputsS).appendTo(addDivS);
        k++;}else alert('Maximum number of contacts reached.')
    return false;
    });
```

So my question is - how to show my word count based on the newly generated textarea field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work...

```
<script>
    $( ".cTxtW-<?php echo $k;?>" ).keyup(function () {
        count('.cTxtW-<?php echo $k;?>', 'count-<?php echo $k;?>');
    });
</script>
```

You were passing in the result of the count function as an event handler for `keyup`.  By putting it in an anonymous function it will only run it when the even takes place.

Comment: Thanks Archer, can you tell me how to add this line to the appended html because I can't append <script></script> because it closes the tag. `<script>$( ".cTxtW-"+k ).keyup(function (){count(".cTxtW-"+k, "#count-"+k);});</script>` this has to go after the <p></p> tag somehow so that I can have it added after each new textarea. Right?

Comment: thanks man. Your suggestion about binding it to the textarea was great.

Comment: Ideally, you'd have the script once and make it work for all textareas.    I'm not sure what your problem with the script tags is though, since you're adding them through php.  I've only ever had issues adding script tags through javascript itself.

Comment: that was my problem, I'm appending them with JS. It is only the first set of inputs that are generated with php. Cheerz